# How do I initialize non-static class members and not get the C2864 error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a thingy and today I got the C2864 Error. I am new to C++ so I'm actually kind of lost.

```
#ifndef MONSTER_ZOMBIE_H
#define MONSTER_ZOMBIE_H

// class definition
class CZombie : public CBaseMonster {
public:
    virtual void Spawn(void);
    virtual void Precache(void);
    virtual void HandleAnimEvent(MonsterEvent_t *pEvent);
    virtual void PainSound(void);
    virtual void DeathSound(void);
    virtual void AlertSound(void);
    virtual void IdleSound(void);
    virtual void AttackSound(void);
    virtual void TraceAttack(entvars_t *pevAttacker, float flDamage, Vector vecDir, TraceResult *ptr, int bitsDamageType);

    virtual bool CheckRangeAttack1(float flDot, float flDist) { return false; }
    virtual bool CheckRangeAttack2(float flDot, float flDist) { return false; }

    virtual int TakeDamage(entvars_t *pevInflictor, entvars_t *pevAttacker, float flDamage, int bitsDamageType);
    virtual int IgnoreConditions(void);
    virtual int Classify(void);

    virtual int Save(CSave &save);
    virtual int Restore(CRestore &restore);

    static TYPEDESCRIPTION m_SaveData[];

    static const char *pAttackSounds[];
    static const char *pIdleSounds[];
    static const char *pAlertSounds[];
    static const char *pPainSounds[];
    static const char *pDeathSounds[];
    static const char *pAttackHitSounds[];
    static const char *pAttackMissSounds[];

protected:
    BOOL  m_flDebug = false;
    float m_flBulletDR = 0.0;
    float m_flNextFlinch;
    float m_flHitgroupHead;
    float m_flHitgroupChest;
    float m_flHitgroupStomach;
    float m_flHitgroupArm;
    float m_flHitgroupLeg;
    float m_flDmgOneSlash;
    float m_flDmgBothSlash;
};

#endif // MONSTER_ZOMBIE_H
```

Visual Studio says that It's BOOL m_flDebug = false; and float m_flBulletDR = 0.0; are the cause of the error, but I just don't really know how to fix this.
All I tried was to move these two lines out of "protected:" and the code actually compiles after that, but said zombie just becomes invulnerable!
I looked at the similar questions here but didn't really learn anything from explanations there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are trying only becomes legal with C++11. So change your compiler options to be at least C++11 (not sure if this is possible with Visual Studio 2010, you really should upgrade your compiler as well).

Or do things the old fashioned way with a constructor.

```
class CZombie : public CBaseMonster {
public:
    CZombie() : m_flDebug(false), m_flBulletDR(0.0) {}
    ...
};
```

If you really don't know about constructors then there are some serious gaps in your C++ knowledge.